# How do I know what direction a road is drawn in OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, editing, road

I'm trying to add a cycleway bike track to one side of a road, but I can't tell which side is left or right. [The docs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3acycleway#Cycle_tracks) say "relative to the direction in which the way was drawn in the editor" , but using the iD editor I can't tell how an existing road is drawn. It also doesn't give me any visual clues as to which direction the road is pointed at.

Comment: iD only displays the direction of the road when certain tags are present, for example *oneway=yes*. You could temporarily add this tag in order to see the direction of the way. But this approach is error-prone because you could forget to remove it later :/

Answer (score 1):

For advanced editing, I suggest to switch over to the editor JOSM.

In JOSM, the way gets arrows in the direction while the way is in editing mode.

Comment: You can also tell in Potlatch 2: when you select a way, the little helper box in the lower right will show the general direction of the way.